# Google BigQuery running forever

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a BigQuery query everyday and it works perfectly but today (2015-08-10) it's taking forever (5,000sec+) and not returning the results or an error, just continue running..

Is there a problem with Google BigQuery today, or is this a bug with BigQuery?

the query job id:job_ijIQidyFErmMaxO5AGuJuHWMAgA

It has been running since 10:30 GMT today and still running

The query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT a1, a2, b2, b1, a3, a4, INTEGER(b3), b4
FROM (SELECT a1, a2, MAX(a3) a3, MAX(a4) a4
      FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(t.a_, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'),
                                           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
      WHERE a4 > 0
      GROUP BY a1, a2) a
JOIN EACH (SELECT b1, b2, MAX(b3) b3, MAX(b4) b4
           FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(t.b_, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'),
                                                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
           WHERE INTEGER(b3) IN (0,2)
           GROUP BY b1, b2) b
ON a.a1 = b.b1 AND a.a2 = b.b2
```

This query runs everyday and was running perfectly until today where it doesn't returns the data or an error.

I tried to run a date where the query was successful (2015-07-10) and I get the same problem, continues running.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem today. Query is part of a CRON job that ran yesterday without issue, but today isn't completing (stilling _running_ after several hours). However, some of the other queries that ran in conjunction with this extended running query do finish in usual amount of time (30 secs).

Comment: FYI mine eventually finished ~5 hours later.

Answer (score 1):

We've rolled out some updates to our query engine which are intended to address intermittent slow queries. If you see this behavior again, please send us another job ID!

For suspected bugs, we recommend filing a bug here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues

Comment: Queries still run forever...job_cW8INWaqUbnF0dA24-sRWR_s88w

Comment: Did this query (or a similar query) complete faster previously? If so, when did you notice the change? Please file a bug at the above link so that we can track the issue.

Comment: I tried to break it down to pieces and found that there was a "resource exceeded..." in one of the sub-queries. I guess there is a time-out in the master query is related to that.

Comment: A "resources exceeded" in a subquery would trigger an immediate failure in the parent query if it were hit. More likely, you have some other expensive operation in the parent query that is consuming lots of time. Obviously it's possible to write resource-intensive queries with BigQuery, so the most important thing to know is why you felt that this query was taking too long (e.g., previously ran fast) and when you noticed the change.

Comment: when i limited the number of records in the sub query it returned in reasonable time. when i removed the limit, it timed out. when I broke it down to pieces, the sub query returned "resource exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

Try to the save the results to a destination table, and mark "allow large results" option under show options -> results size.
For me, this usually solves such issues.